# Google Maps Preview doesn't use query strings

Tags: google-maps

Can anybody shed some light on the URLs - how they are parsed, if at all - that google maps preview uses? Without the standard query string, I'm kind of confused.

Like this one:

https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!4m19!3m18!1m1!1sSt+John's%2C+NL%2C+Canada!1m5!1sAntigua!2s0x8c129363ff620915%3A0xc6dbec600cc1c7a3!3m2!3d17.0746557!4d-61.8175207!2e4!3m8!1m3!1d13003228!2d-67.8071628!3d28.8987239!3m2!1i1280!2i698!4f13.1&fid=0

I understand this may be a broad question, but any information at all would be helpful.

Thanks to the SO community in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's basically a special case of a query string. But the `#!` form is probably more suitable for use with JavaScript, while the `?` form is what you would use in a PHP file. (That, or it's a way of differentiating between a JS-based page and a PHP-based page.) <sup>[citation needed]</sup>

So just take the `window.location.hash` property,

```
#!data=!4m19!3m18!1m1[...]4f13.1&fid=0
```

remove the two characters at the beginning,

```
data=!4m19!3m18!1m1[...]4f13.1&fid=0
```

then you have a query string that some sort of JavaScript function can parse into an object.